# Why have the leaves fallen off my lemon tree?

Tags: leaves, fruit-trees, indoors, lemons

My potted lemon tree is about 15 yes old.  Repotted about 4 yrs ago.  Always produced lots of lemons and was healthy. This winter it gradually lost all its leaves and some branches died.lives indoors in the winter and outside in zone 6 in summer.I use citrus fertilizer. No noticeable bugs, occasionally scale which I remove manually.

Comment: Hi, a picture would be a great help

Comment: I'm going with ... root problem. Do not fix with fertilizer, but less water.

Comment: I tried taking a picture,but can't  figure out the site.  The icon is grayed out.